# I just want my client to say hello to my server but can't

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, asyncsocket

OK this is such a simple problem but its driving me so mad that I have had to drink a whole jug of water to calm myself down.

**EDIT**

Added c# in the tag too, a c# answer will be fine too.

Basically I am implementing this asynchronous client/server example here on microsoft's website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx .

Now I have a project instance running the server and the server is OK, and just waiting for a connection.

I am trying to understand the asynhronous communication model in .net and I simply want my client.vb to say hello to server who is listening locally on port 2000.

The code in the microsoft example is long and I am working to understand it bit by bit , but for now I just want a SIMPLE few lines code to say "hello" to my waiting server.

```
Dim ipHostInfo As IPHostEntry = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName())
    Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList(0)
    Dim localEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 2000)
    clientSocket.BeginConnect("localhost", 2000, AddressOf ConnectionMade, clientSocket)
```

The above isn't working, I get a null pointer exception. There are so many callback, acceptcallback and other methods in microsoft example that I am sure i will understand fine soon, but for now it is incredibly confusing.

Please save me from wearing my laptop has a hat and help.Just a simple "hello" string to server and my life will be a happy one.
thanks

Comment: I had to drink two monsters just to make it through your question :)

Comment: Drinking a 'jug' of water just makes me feel bloated, which does not enhance my calm.

Comment: I've added some more tags because this isn't really a C# or vb.net issue, but specifically related to async communication

Comment: Why don't you try using SignalR instead?

Comment: SignalR? i'm not there yet. I just want to send a "hello" string to the server.

Comment: where's your declaration of clientSocket?

Comment: At a guess, I'd say your problem is because you're passing `clientSocket` into 
`clientSocket.BeginConnect`. Perhaps you should be passing `localEndPoint` instead?

Comment: @JohnKraft : uh... that got me thinking..i use this `Dim clientSocket As System.Net.Sockets.Socket` , but I now that you mention it, i think it is not being assigned, I think i need to assign a value somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your code to create an example, and the only way I can make it give me a null reference exception is if I don't properly instantiate the socket.  But without seeing your declaration of clientSocket or the ConnectionMade method, it's hard to tell.

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (ipAddress, 2000);
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IPv4);
clientSocket.BeginConnect("http://www.google.com", 80, new AsyncCallback(method), clientSocket);
```

Comment: OH YES! that works, thats half my problem solved... now how about that pesky "hello" message? :)